# Puzzled: I have 3 spaces (combination) and 3 categorical values. How do I compute all combinations of values?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This feels like it should be easier than it is but if I have values A B C
I could have

A A A

A A B

e.t.c

A C B

C C A

e.t.c.

Is there a simple way of computing them in say c#, javascript, python or psuedo code? I basically want a 2d array with all combinations in one dimension and the values in another.

Comment: This kinda feels like counting in base2

Comment: Counting in base 2 (or especially base 3!) is a good insight

Comment: Lol that's exactly what I meant. Not editting my original comment so the world can see I'm an idiot!

Comment: in python you can "cheat", it's already in the standard library: `from itertools import product` then `print(list(''.join(x) for x in product('ABC', repeat=3)))`

Comment: In pseudo code and for a small number of elements, you can use a nested for-loop: `for x0 in "ABC": for x1 in "ABC": for x2 in "ABC": print(x0,x1,x2)`

Comment: As for keywords, what you're asking for is called "the Cartesian product of {A,B,C} with itself with itself" or "the Cartesian product of {A,B,C} with itself three times" or "the 3rd Cartesian power of {A,B,C}" or something similar. See [Wikipedia: Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_products_of_several_sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the ways you count N digits is really each digit prepended to all the ways you count N-1 digits.  All the ways you count 1 digit, is just all the digits.

With that...

```js
function nCombosOfABC(nDigits) {
  if (nDigits === 1) return ['A', 'B', 'C']
  let result = []
  let n1 = nCombosOfABC(nDigits-1)
  for (let r of n1) {
    for (let letter of ['A', 'B', 'C']) {
      result.push([letter, ...r])
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(nCombosOfABC(3))
```

Or, as a suggestion made in comments, a more literal add (in little-endian base 3)...

```js
const addOne = string => {
    const adder = { A: { value: 'B' }, B: { value: 'C' }, C: { value: 'A', carry: true } }
    const digits = string.split('');
    const sum = adder[digits[0]];
    return sum.carry ? sum.value + addOne(digits.slice(1).join('')) : [sum.value, ...digits.slice(1)].join('')
}

for (let n = "AAA"; n != "CCC"; n = addOne(n)) {
    console.log(n)
}
console.log("CCC")
```

Comment: Good answer. I like the use of recursion here. I was over complicating things

Comment: Thanks. Yours must've posted while I was editing my answer. It might be taking the counting metaphor too seriously.

Comment: Yeah, but it worked so what the hell. Much prefer your way though. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So this is a crude solution for those that want to know?
The point of this was to generate every combination of kernel of size and categories combination.

```
public static float[][] GenerateCombinations(int size, float[] categories)
    {
        List<float[]> combinations = new List<float[]>();
        var totalKernels = (int)Math.Pow(categories.Length, size);
        var currentIndexes = new int[size];

        var firstOutput = new float[size];
        combinations.Add(firstOutput);

        for (var i = 1; i < totalKernels; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            var output = new float[size];
            var carry = 0;

            for (var j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    currentIndexes[j]++;
                }
                if (carry != 0)
                {
                    currentIndexes[j] += carry;
                    carry = 0;
                }
                if (currentIndexes[j] >= categories.Length)
                {
                    carry = 1;
                    output[j] = categories[0];
                    currentIndexes[j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    output[j] = categories[currentIndexes[j]];
                }
                Console.Write($" {output[j]}");
            }
            combinations.Add(output);
        }
        return combinations.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: A fun exercise for you would be to be even more literal in counting: write a function called plusOne(string) that advances the least significant "digit" -- the rightmost character -- and carries(the only hard part) if necessary. Then your solution is just "call plusOne up to CCC".  Running out now, but I'll add it here -- if you haven't already -- when I get back

Comment: Yeah I was kinda feeling like it was almost an interview style question. Feel free to add

Comment: I wasn't sure about etiquette-wise, who's answer to edit, so I added a very literal base 3 (little-endian) adder solution to mine. Thanks for the fun. (I'm helping a friend learn coding, and I think I'll present him with this problem).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different approaches in python

### Triple nested loop

We find all possible triplets by iterating on all possible values of the first element, and iterating on all possible values of the second element, and iterating on all possible values of the third element.

- Pros: extremely simple to understand and code;
- Cons: the number of elements per tuple is hard-coded; we'd need a different function if we wanted pairs or quadruplets or quintuplets instead of triplets.

```py
def all_triplets(seq):
    for x in seq:
        for y in seq:
            for z in seq:
                yield (x,y,z)

print(list(all_triplets('AB')))
# [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B')]

print(list(all_triplets('ABC')))
# [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C')]
```

### Recurrence relation

Instead of nested loops, we use a recurrence relation for Cartesian product:

```
product(seq with itself n times) == product(seq, product(seq with itself n-1 times))
```

We will still iterate on all possible values of the first element; but instead of using hard-coded nested loops to iterate on all possible values of the remaining elements, we will use the recurrence relation to get the possible values of the remaining elements.

Like all recurrence relations, it can easily be used to write either an iterative function or a recursive function. Since python is pretty terrible when it comes to recursion, here is an iterative version.

- Pros: the number of elements per tuple is now a parameter;
- Cons: this is harder to understand than the hard-coded nested loop.

```py
def all_n_uplets(seq, n):
    '''assume n >= 1'''
    result = seq
    for _ in range(n-1):
        result = [ (x, *t) for x in seq for t in result ]
    return result

print(all_n_uplets('ABC', 2))
# [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'C')]

print(all_n_uplets('ABC', 3))
# [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C')]
```

### Standard library

Cartesian product is already implemented in python: [it's function `product` in module `itertools`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) It can be used to compute the Cartesian product of several different sequences, or of a sequence with itself.

- Pros: it's already there, no need to reimplement the wheel;
- Cons: the name `itertools.product` is specific to python, if you want to use another language, you'll need to look for the equivalent.

```py
from itertools import product

print(list(product('ABC', repeat=3)))
# [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C')]

print(list(product('ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC')))
# [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C')]
```

Note that searching for library functions forces you to adopt vocabulary that is consistent with the vocabulary used by the community. Make a distinction between the following concepts:

- Cartesian product, or "combinations with replacement";
- powerset, or "set of all subsets";
- permutations;
- combinations (without replacement);
- derangements;
- distinct permutations (for a sequence with duplicates);
- etc.